# Avoid repetitive null checking for arguments in functions calling functions

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, coding-style, clean-architecture

Context:
`getProfilesFromResponse` is a utility function used by `websocketMessageHandler` to parse the profiles from a websocket message.

What's a better and clean design?

1. Should `getProfilesFromResponse` repeat the null checks?
2. Is there a visible performance gain by doing the null checks only once? This is a websocket message callback handler, so its going to be called like 50 times a second due to heavy websocket stream.
3. Should `getProfilesFromResponse` use `response?.data` over `response.data`?

```
function getProfilesFromResponse(response) {
  // should we add null or undefined checks here as well?  

  if ('profiles' in response.data) { // should I instead do response?.data
    // do remaining data manipulations and return the final data
  }
}

function websocketMessageHandler(response) {
  if (!response) {
    // null checks done here
  }
  ...
  ...
  ...
  const profiles = getProfilesFromResponse(response);
  ...
}
```

My Opinion

1. NOPE, we can make a rule for all the functions that are calling `getProfilesFromResponse` to do the null checks themselves. The downside is we are assuming things never go wrong, but my counter argument is we do want things to crash so that people actually make sure they don't call the function with null argument.
2. Not really, it's a O(1) operation. Negligent impact to performance.
3. Prefer `response?.data` as its a little more robust. But since we already know `response` isn't empty, so we can skip it.

Comment: Use middleware for this

Answer (score 0):

1 - No, you should avoid calling `getProfilesFromResponse` if `response` is null, for example, by stopping `websocketMessageHandler` execution:

```
  function websocketMessageHandler(response) {

    if(!response) 
       return; //< avoid further operations
          
    const profiles = getProfilesFromResponse(response);

    // more code here
  }
```

or alternatively:

```
  function websocketMessageHandler(response) {

    if(response) {
      const profiles = getProfilesFromResponse(response);
      // more code here
    } else {
      // do something in case response is null or undefined
    }
  }
```

2 - There is always a benefit avoiding useless operations.

3 - If you properly avoided `getProfilesFromResponse` to be called with null parameter, you don't have to check again, you also avoided an useless function call...

Comment: All this is good, but who will ensure when other people change this code over months, then this constraint will still meet that we do not send null arguments to the `getProfileFromResponse` function? I realise this is a tough question and trade-off needs to be made. I am still curious to know a surprisingly better alternate here.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, why would someone modify this over the months ?